# Как заменить стандартный курсор браузера на кастомный

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Хочу убрать стандартный скролл браузера, поставить неширокий красивый как на смартфонах.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Изменить полосу прокрутки на чистом css в Mozilla Firefox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/722260/%d0%98%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-css-%d0%b2-mozilla-firefox)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Можно сделать и с помощью **css.** [Пример.](https://yraaa.ru/scripts/stilizatsiya-polosyi-prokrutki-s-pomoschyu-css)
P.S. *Если я правильно понял задание, то уже настроите под себя:)*

```css
body {
  min-height: 250vh;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  width: 5px;
  height: 0px
}

/* Цвет дорожки, по которой двигается бегунок прокрутки. */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: #ecedee
}

/* Цвет бегунка полосы, а так же его закругление. */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background-color: #6dc0c8;
}

/* Цвет бегунка при наведении на него курсора. */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: #56999f;
}

/* Основная ширина полосы прокрутки. */
::-webkit-resizer {
  width: 4px;
  height: 0px
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 4px;
}
```

## ИЛИ:

[Подробнее...](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jquery-nicescroll/)

```css
body {
  min-height: 250vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.nicescroll/3.7.6/jquery.nicescroll.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(
    function() {
      $("html").niceScroll({
        cursorcolor:"#6dc0c8", 
        background:"#ecedee", 
        autohidemode:"false", 
        cursorborder:"none", 
        cursorborderradius:"none"
      });
  });
</script>
```

> It supports `DIVs`, `IFrames`, `textarea`, and document page (`body`) scrollbars. Compatible with all desktop browser: **Firefox 4+, Chrome
>   5+, Safari 4+ (win/mac), Opera 10+, IE 6+**. (all A-grade browsers)

Comment: Мужик спасибо, я обрадовался сначала что на css решение, но на мозиле обычный скролл!)

Comment: опять же , насчёт обновленного твоего ответа, решение не кроссбраузерно, на мозилле опять не работает)

Comment: 57.0 )))вот недавно обновленная которая с обновленным дизайном

Comment: пардон , всё работает!)спасибо

Comment: Для неопытных, как я: во-первых, это первое решение, которое работает. Во-вторых, параметр 250vh я поменял на 80vh, потому что изначально внизу появился большой белый "подвал". С заменой на 80 (и менее) всё стало на свои места.