# HTML CSS Как сделать кастомный скроллбар

Tags: html, css, scss

Проблема возникла с изменением скроллбара для блока (div). Использовал псевдоклассы и свойства:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar

scrollbar-width: 1200px;
```

Но все без успешно. Почему-то chrome не принимает данные изменения, а ошибку не выводит. Мой код SCSS:

```
.benefits {
    height: 600px;
    &::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 4px;
        height: 4px;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }
}
```

Comment: По нормальному - только через JS

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как заменить стандартный курсор браузера на кастомный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/747012/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения данного вопроса через -webkit я напрямую задал overflow-y:scroll стилизуемому блоку после чего стили применились.

Пример:

```
.benefits {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.benefits::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(26, 24, 47, 0.15);
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 200px;
}

.benefits::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #1A182F;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```